# code in javascript that ask for start and end time for a particular behavior

Tags: javascript, timer

i am making a Quiz app and i want a functionality that should start quiz based on start time and end time. for example quiz should start at 9:00 AM and should stop and 9:20 AM. 
time should be provided by Admin
and after end time quiz should be submitted automatically.

Comment: i dont know javascript at all.i have completed my project using (php and mysql) . the only things that is left is countdown timer. Admin should upload the start and the end time of quiz i.e start (2015/09/30 16:00:00) end (2015/09/30 16:30:00) and after time expire quiz should be submitted automatically. i have checked this cannot be implement in php and i dont know javascript .

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript's Date().getTime() we can call for the current time in milliseconds (which is the number of milliseconds since midnight, 1 Jan 1970):

```
var curTime = new Date().getTime();
```

Now we calculate the amount of time in milliseconds we wish to timeout for:

- 20*60*1000 = 120000 milliseconds
- (Twenty minutes)*(seconds in minute)*(milliseconds in a second)

You could also rewrite it as to adjust by minutes only:

```
var min = 20, var timeLimit = min*60000;
```

Then, set a timeout based on our current time and the time limit:

```
var timeout = curTime+timeLimit;
```

Finally we use this to compare the current time to and if it's past (greater than) the timeout we call a close function for the quiz and optionally display a message.

```
if(new Date().getTime() > timeout) {
  alert("The quiz has expired");
}
```

The finished code looks a bit like this:

```
var curTime = new Date().getTime(), min = 20, var timeLimit = min*60000, timeout = curTime+timeLimit;
if(new Date().getTime() > timeout) {
  alert("The quiz has expired");
}
```

From here you can derive any number of modifications. Say you want to set the the availability between two determined time periods. You would need a method of input that was human readable for the start and end time. So the conversion of dates and times to milliseconds would be necessary.

To store the date you will want a set of dropdown menus which can then store the chosen date for both start and end times. An example dropdown would look as shown:

```
<select id="quizStartHours">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  ...
  <option value="12">12</option>
</select>
```

You will want to make the above for each start and end for hours, minutes (increments of 5 suggested in this case), month, month day (limited by number of months varyingly, 28-31). If you wish to only quiz on same days not over a period of days you could simplify it into a single year & month for both start & finish - hours & minutes.

One project that may help you on date dropdown menus is **ComboDate**, which may also store input into the date() format for us to use with `var curTime = new Date().getTime();`.

Now we store the user input. To store it on a server, you'll have to get into ajax a bit and server side variables. I'm not too sure how that works at the moment, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399464/saving-javascript-variable-in-server-side-variable-vbscript) is an inquiry regarding how to do so using vbscript to help you if you wish to do so. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable can assist if that's an issue.

For now, I'll continue with a focus on local variable storing for example purposes. Here is an example of how to record the user input from the hour dropdown:

```
var e = document.getElementById("quizStartHours");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

In order to use the input we must store it in milliseconds that will work with the `curTime`, `date()` does so out of the box:

```
var quizStartDate = new Date(quizStartYear, quizStartMonth, quizStartDay, quizStartHours, quizStartMinutes);

var quizEndDate = new Date(quizEndYear, quizEndMonth, quizEndDay, quizEndHours, quizEndMinutes);
```

You may learn more about how date() behaves [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp).

Now that we have our start and end dates we can now check for availability based on the current time (`curTime`) and our `quizStartDate` & `quizEndDate` variables:

```
var quizAvaliable = quizEndDate > curTime && curTime > quizStartDate;
```

The final code would look something like this:

```
// on quiz listing & opening check for curTime
var curTime = new Date().getTime(), quizAvaliable = quizEndDate > curTime && curTime > quizStartDate;
if(quizAvaliable) {
    alert("The quiz is open");
    //allow access to quiz itself (menu linking, page publicity)
}
else if(curTime > quizEndDate) {
    alert("The quiz has expired");
    //save then close quiz, in that order
}
else {
    alert("The quiz has not begun");
}
```

Hopefully this helps with figuring out how to do all of this. Here I focused primarily on the separate steps of the process, and how to perform each. However this is client side, for security you may want to go server side, which is what **Ajax** (asynchronous JavaScript and XML) coding is for.

Best of luck!

Any items in bold should be looked up if you wish to learn more if you haven't already.

Comment: thanks you Leviscus Tempris for explaining  in so much detail but i am new to javascript i have copy pasted your code but i did not get any result.